# Programantic Diff

Tags: terminal, diff

I'm localising a piece of Javascript (the github repo is [here](https://github.com/joereddington/azulejoe)) for Spanish speaking users. I have both the English and Spanish text as PDFs and I have the software in English.

The pdfs look like this (100 slides):

[image]

...and I could do the localisation with copy and paste, but that's going to take a while (plus there are other languages coming down the pipeline so I'm looking for a version I could do grammatically.

If I copy-paste both the files into a text editor and then do opendiff on them, then I get the translation I'm looking for:

[image]

But what I want is to be able to access this from the terminal - I want to be able to write the command:

getDiffedLine  english.txt 77 spanish.txt

Which would find line 77 in the English version of the text file and return it's best match in the Spanish file.  (It might say 'it's one of these seven lines', but I can work with that)

Do I have any options or is this a blatant misuse of diff?

Comment: There is no such thing as a blantent misuse of any unix command.  Well maybe the guy using nroff to convert decimal numbers to roman numerals could belong in this catagory. :-)